# Why can't I get any query result?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to retrieve some users from a Parse database:
[image]

But I always get zero data.

Everyone shares the same geoPoint so this query could just as well be all-inclusive.

Here's my code:

```
func getUsers(withinGeoCoordinate geoPoint:PFGeoPoint, withinRadius radius:Int?) -> Bool {
    var query = PFQuery(className:"User")

    query.whereKey(ParsePostLocationKey, nearGeoPoint:geoPoint, withinKilometers:2)

    gFriendsArray = query.findObjects() as [PFUser]

    if gFriendsArray.count > 0 {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

I'm assuming that to access "Users" class (as in the posted image), I use the following:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"User")  <-- query the class 'User'
```

Question: Why am I not getting any data (with or without query qualifiers)?

> (lldb) po gFriendsArray 0 values  {}

Comment: Have you tried disabling the filter by location?

Comment: yes.   I had commented out the query.whereKey... but result is still zero.

Comment: Maybe you don't have the permission to query users, thus the query returns empty resultset. Try creating a new table, enter some data and run a similar query

Comment: It appears you're spot on.  I created another class and loaded it with trivial data; and did a query it worked.

Comment: How do I change the permission setting per object so I can query it?

Answer (score 0):

Per feedback, I created another class and populated it.
Then I did the same query and got data.

So apparently the original class, which was created by another user... does not have the correct permission status for me to query it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason why the query produces no results is that you have to use the `_User` class name instead of `User`. If you try to delete the User class (More -> Drop class) it asks for confirmation, for which you have to enter the class name, and it reports it as `_User`. I think they prefix system tables by an underscore to prevent name conflicts with your own tables.